# consuming message in client in kafka-python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am new to Kafka. By taking help from a few online tutorials of kafka-python I have written following piece of code:

```
   from kafka import SimpleProducer, KafkaClient, KafkaConsumer
   kafka =  KafkaClient("localhost:9092")
   producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
   producer.send_messages(b'my-topic', b'this method', b'Hello World')
   consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic',
                     group_id='my_group',
                     bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
   for message in consumer:
       print("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,
                                         message.offset, message.key,
                                         message.value))
```

But the problem is that in that last for loop code execution is stuck which I cannot figure out.

Comment: I think I found the answer. It seems to consume message from SimpleProducer consumer has to be instance of SimpleConsumer, because after doing that change the code seems to work. If I am wrong please rectify. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**You original code is right.** I run your code. KafkaConsumer can be used to consume messages. If you open another console, and run the same original code, you will see the output.

In http://kafka-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apidoc/kafka.consumer.html, there are lots of Consumer classes, such as SimpleConsumer, KafkaConsumer, Consumer, and so on.  Why you code is stuck in the for-loop? Because the consumer in your code is set to consume **new** messages by default. In this case, the messages produced by producer.send_messages() function would not be consumed by the consumer.

By the way, if you use SimpleConsumer, you can use seek() to set the offset of messages you would like to consume.